# Binomial distribution in exponential form

Tags: generalized-linear-model, binomial-distribution, exponential-family

I am trying to find out if I am doing this right:

I have started with:
$f(y)=\binom{n}{y}(\frac{\mu}{n})^y(1-\frac{\mu}{n})^{n-y}$

This is what I get:
**Result: $exp[ylog(\frac{\mu}{n-\mu}) - nlog(1+e^\theta)+log\binom{n}{y}]$**
$\theta=log(\frac{\mu}{n-\mu})$
$b(\theta)=nlog(1+e^\theta)$
$\phi=1$
$a(\phi)=1$
$c(\phi,y)=log(\binom{n}{y})$

However, I found this solution that looks similar but **different** to mine and values of a and b seem to be different: 
[image: found solution]

So, I noticed they are using $\pi$ instead of $\frac{u}{n}$ so I am not sure if the solutions are equivalent or I made a mistake somewhere along the line.

So I have a couple of questions

Is it possible to have 2 different solutions with different values for *a* and *b* and maybe *c*?
Also, in the notes I have $a(\phi)==\phi$ in the examples I have but it might not be true everywhere?

Comment: Thanks @Xi'an, it is similar but I don't think it covers my questions or the discrepancy in $b(\theta)$, is it with an n or without it

Comment: @whuber, I fail to see the answers for my questions on the duplicate you linked, any help for a newbie?